# Android Studio bottom navigation bar problem(RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

I added a bottom navigation bar to my activity, after which my RecycleView stopped showing. The log gives an error "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

As you can see I have attached an adapter for RecyclerView. So why do I keep getting this error?

I have read other questions related to the same problem but none of them help.

Here is my source code:

```
class Main : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object{
    val INTENT_PARCELABLE = "OBJECT_INTENT"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)


    val foodList = listOf<Food>(
        Food(
            R.drawable.food1,
            "Гамбургер",
            "300Г",
            "190Р",
            "Булка, котлета говяжья, сыр, салат айсберг,\n" +
                    "лук, маринованные огурцы, соус",
        ),
        Food(
            R.drawable.food2,
            "Шаурма",
            "400Г",
            "139Р",
            "Лаваш, куриное филе, салат, лук, соус\n"
        ),
        Food(
            R.drawable.food3,
            "Закрытая пицца",
            "278Г",
            "109Р",
            "Фирменная лепешка, соус, куриное филе,\n" +
                    "пекинская капуста, помидоры, сыр,\n" +
                    "соус цезарь"
        ),
        Food(
            R.drawable.food4,
            "Вок",
            "250Г",
            "129Р",
            "Куриное филе, лапша удон, овощной микс,\n" +
                    "лук, чеснок, имбирь, кунжут, соус"
        ),
    )

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rcView)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@Main, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    recyclerView.adapter = FoodAdapter(this,foodList){
        val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_PARCELABLE,it)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
    val firstFragment = FirstFragment()
    val secondFragment = SecondFragment()

    setCurrentFragment(firstFragment)

    val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.btm_nav)

    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener  {
        when (it.itemId){
            R.id.home -> setCurrentFragment(firstFragment)
            R.id.card -> setCurrentFragment(secondFragment)
        }
        true
    }
}
fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.fl_wrapper,fragment)
        commit()
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you post the `FoodAdapter` code?

Answer (score 0):

By using bottomnav, you should use single activity pattern. In your MainActivity, you need to use fragmentcontainer as layout, and after container, put a bottom nav bar, that’s would be better for architecture. Also don’t forget to create nav_graph file into nav folder in your res